# Textview Values of counter changes after scrolling Listview?

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, listadapter

***The Problem is*** :

*I am having list of products in listview and a textview following incremenat/decrement buttons. If I perform increment and decrement on first item of the listview it changes to the other listview positions also while performing scrolling on it.*

***what all I have tried so far:***

- [TextView's value changed while scrolling listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722771/textviews-value-changed-while-scrolling-listview)
- [TextView in listview rows showing repeated values on scroll in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17142117/textview-in-listview-rows-showing-repeated-values-on-scroll-in-android)
- [Duplicated entries in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8261376/duplicated-entries-in-listview?lq=1)
- [Android list items are changing when scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26622536/android-list-items-are-changing-when-scrolling)

*I was not able to solve my problem with none of these.
I am stuck with this problem from last three days. Any one please help me with it I will be really grateful to you. Thanks*

***This is my code of Adapter Class:***

```
class SubProductsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private Context context;
  //  private ArrayList<String> list;
    DBHelper dbHelper;
    ArrayList<AddedProducts> arrayList;
    boolean exists;
    String addedQuant;
    String quant;
    String discounted;
    String finalPrice;
    URI uri;
    private List<SubProductData> subProductDataList = null;


    public SubProductsListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<SubProductData> list){
        this.context = context;
        this.subProductDataList = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return subProductDataList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return subProductDataList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }





    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView == null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.sub_fragment_list_items,null,false);
            holder.ItemImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_image);
            holder.txtItemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
            holder.disCountedPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.discounted_price);
            holder.finalPrice = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.final_price);
            holder.quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
            holder.addedQuantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_quantity);
            holder.addItem = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.add);
            holder.removeItem = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.remove);
             holder.v = (Vibrator) this.context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                           convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }



        /**  set item name from the arrayList   */

        holder.txtItemName.setText(subProductDataList.get(position).getProductName());
        final String url = subProductDataList.get(position).getProductImage();
        String parentUrl = "http://test//";
        String finalUrl = parentUrl+url;



        try {
             uri  = new URI(finalUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        Picasso.with(context)
                    .load(String.valueOf(uri)) // loaded image
                .placeholder(R.drawable.categorydefault)     // thumbnail image
                .error(R.drawable.categorydefault)   // if unable to load image or fetch image from server
                    .into(holder.ItemImage);


        String productPrice = subProductDataList.get(position).getProductPrice();
        double myProductFianlPrice = Double.parseDouble(productPrice);
        myProductFianlPrice =Double.parseDouble(new DecimalFormat("##.####").format(myProductFianlPrice));

        holder.finalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(myProductFianlPrice));


        /**  Strike discounted price   */
        holder.disCountedPrice.setPaintFlags(holder.disCountedPrice.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

         addedQuant = holder.addedQuantity.getText().toString();
         discounted = holder.disCountedPrice.getText().toString();
         finalPrice =  holder.finalPrice.getText().toString();



        /** Setting quantitiy of products from databse to textview  */

        final String itemName =subProductDataList.get(position).getProductName();
        arrayList = dbHelper.getAllProducts();
        exists = false;

        for (AddedProducts hmap : arrayList)
        {
            if (hmap.getTitle().equals(itemName))
            {
                exists = true;
                break;
            }}

        if (exists){

            Cursor id = dbHelper.getQuantityOfProduct(itemName);
            quant = null;
            id.moveToFirst();
            if (id.moveToFirst()) {
                quant   = id.getString(id.getColumnIndex("qty"));
                Log.e(quant,"this is my quantity");
            }
            holder.addedQuantity.setText(quant);
        }




        /**  Add items to the cart   */
        holder.addItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String present_value_string = holder.addedQuantity.getText().toString();
                int present_value_int = Integer.parseInt(present_value_string);
                present_value_int++;


                holder.addedQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(present_value_int));
                addedQuant = holder.addedQuantity.getText().toString();


                float tot = Float.parseFloat(finalPrice) * present_value_int;
                int dis = Integer.parseInt(discounted) * present_value_int;
                String itemName =subProductDataList.get(position).getProductName();
                String proIds = subProductDataList.get(position).getProductId();
                String proModel = subProductDataList.get(position).getProductModel();

                Log.e(proModel,"productModel");

                final String url = subProductDataList.get(position).getProductImage();
                String parentUrl = "http://falconet.co.in/jubstore/image/";
                String finalUrl = parentUrl+url;



                try {
                    uri  = new URI(finalUrl.replaceAll(" ", "%20"));
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                boolean test =  dbHelper.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(itemName);


                if (!test)
                {
                    dbHelper.insertProduct(context,itemName,proIds,finalPrice, discounted,present_value_int,proModel,String.valueOf(uri),tot,dis);

                }
                else
                {
                    //item already exists
                    Cursor id = dbHelper.getQuantityData(itemName);

                    String myId = null;
                    id.moveToFirst();
                    if (id.moveToFirst()) {
                        myId   = id.getString(id.getColumnIndex("id"));
                        Log.e(myId,"this is my id");

                    }

                    float tots = Float.parseFloat(finalPrice) * present_value_int;
                    dbHelper.updateProduct(Integer.parseInt(myId),present_value_int,tots);
                    Log.e(String.valueOf(tots),"updatedtotalcheck");


                }


            }
        });

       /**  remove items from the cart   */
        holder.removeItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String present_value_string = holder.addedQuantity.getText().toString();
                int present_value_int = Integer.parseInt(present_value_string);
                if (present_value_int > 0) {
                    present_value_int--;
                    holder.addedQuantity.setText(String.valueOf(present_value_int));
                    holder.v.vibrate(300);

                    String itemName =subProductDataList.get(position).getProductName();
                    boolean test =  dbHelper.CheckIsDataAlreadyInDBorNot(itemName);

                    if (test)
                    {

                        //item already exists
                        Cursor id = dbHelper.getQuantityData(itemName);

                        String myId = null;
                        id.moveToFirst();
                        if (id.moveToFirst()) {
                            myId   = id.getString(id.getColumnIndex("id"));
                            Log.e(myId,"this is my id");
                        }
                        float tots = Float.parseFloat(finalPrice) * Integer.parseInt(addedQuant);
                        dbHelper.updateProduct(Integer.parseInt(myId),present_value_int,tots);

                    }
                }


                /** if textview quantity is equal to zero remove product from cart    */

                if (holder.addedQuantity.getText().toString() == "0"){


                    Cursor id = dbHelper.getQuantityData(itemName);
                    String myId = null;
                    id.moveToFirst();
                    if (id.moveToFirst()) {
                        myId   = id.getString(id.getColumnIndex("id"));
                        SubProductsListAdapter.this.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    if (myId != null) {
                        dbHelper.deleteProduct(Integer.valueOf(myId));

                    }
                }


            }});

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        Button removeItem;
        Button addItem;
        TextView disCountedPrice,finalPrice,quantity,addedQuantity;
        ImageView ItemImage;
        TextView txtItemName;
        Vibrator v;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add one variable in holder class that store value of quantity and set last quantity in it.

```
class ViewHolder{
      int  quanity
    }
```

store that quantity

```
 holder.quantity = your quantity
```

now you can get last quantity value from holder and place it to your textview.

```
  /**  set item name from the arrayList   */

        holder.txtItemName.setText(subProductDataList.get(position).getProductName());
holder.txtQuanity.setText(holder.quantity)
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: problem is still the same :(

Comment: where you saving `holder.quantity = your quantity` in `setOnClickListener` right? @ArulHarsh

Comment: yes I am saving it two times first on activity start second on clickListner

Comment: no just add quantity on + - click only because in that you will get actual value and for the rest it will 0 by default cause it is int

Comment: I have saved the already added quantites in DB and then I display it on the textviews